# How do i find what is leaking in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I have some C# code. I use code analyses to find all the places where i am not using `using(){}` or not calling dispose. That is done. Yet it still leaks. The code doesn't call DllImport except two functions (SetWindowPos, SetForegroundWindow) but those are never called (main instance doesnt use it. Other instance do but they live for a few seconds).

Somehow this code is leaking. How do i find out what the problem is?

Comment: What makes you think the code is leaking memory? And your title and question mentions `[C#]`, but your tags say `[C++]`. Is C++ relevant here?

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why this isn't a real question? @Insilico: The C++ was a typo. (hopefully the `using` keyword and tagging .NET made that clear). What makes me think its leaking? The fact it gets up to 1.5gb in memory and throws an out of memory exception makes me think its leaking. In the past i never seen it go more then 80mb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory leaks in Managed code are usually due to objects being held in memory by an unintended reference. Events handers are common culprits here.

You're going to want to get hold of a memory profiling tool. [SciTech's .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) is probably the best, though [JetBrains' dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html#Memory_profiling) and [RedGate's ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/index2) are also both good.

Microsoft has a free profiling tool, [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273), that can be used, though it's a bit more complicated. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2009/03/13/speedy-c-part-4-using---and-understanding---clr.aspx) for some guidance.

The [DRONE profiler for .NET](http://www.droneprofiler.com/index.aspx) seems to have a free personal license, though I am not familiar with the tool myself. They have an article on finding memory leaks with their profiler [here](http://www.droneprofiler.com/articles/finding_memory_leaks_using_drone_profiler.aspx).

The higher end versions of Visual Studio also contain profiling tools. MSDN contains the [documentation on how to use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks i'll accept once i find the culprit of the problem

Comment: It turns out i had a for loop that was never-ending putting a page i parse into a list until a memory exception. I had a `continue` forgetting the loop was a link list and i have to increment it. I rewrote it so i increment it at the 2nd line of the loop (first is making a ptr/ref to the current link). There is a sleep() in it which is why it took many minutes and used up no CPU before i notice it. Its also on another thread (nonmain). ugh, bugs.

Comment: oops i meant a while loop. I used SciTech's .NET Memory Profiler, spent some time figuring out how to use it and used 'memory held' to track the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your application using the profiler built in to Visual Studio (Premium and Ultimate), or invest in a tool like [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/index2).

Comment: +1. I do have access to VS with said profiler. I didnt realize it had memory profiling as i use C++ most of the time (which i never leak and their C++ profiler doesnt do IIRC). I'll accept when i track the problem down